# Invert Arnold's Cat map - negative array indexes

Tags: image, encryption, shuffle, pixel

I'm trying to implement [Arnold's Cat map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold's_cat_map) for N*N images using the following formula

```
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {  
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {  
                  desMatrix[(i + j) % N][(i + 2 * j) % N] = srcMatrix[i][j];  
                }  
            }
```

To invert the process I do:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {  
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {  
                  srcMatrix[(j-i) % N][(2*i-j) % N] = destMatrix[i][j];  
                }  
            }
```

Is the implementation correct?

It seems to me that for certain values of j and i I might get negative indexes from (j-i) and (2*i-j); how should I handle those cases, since matrix indexes are only positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when a modulo (%) operation needs to work on negative indexes, you can simply add the modulo argument as many times as it's needed. Since

```
x % N  == ( x + a*N ) % N
```

for all natural a's, and in this case you have i and j constrained in [0, N), then you can write (N + i - j) and ensure that even if i is 0 and j is N-1 (or even N for that matter), the result will always be non-negative. By the same token, (2*N + i - 2*j) or equivalently (i + 2*(N-j)) is always non-negative.

In this case, though, this is not necessary. To invert your map, you would repeat the forward step *reversing the assignments*. Since the matrix has unary determinant and is area-preserving, you're assured that you'll get all your points eventually (i.e. covering M(i+1) will yield a covering of M(i)).

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        newMatrix[i][j] = desMatrix[(i + j) % N][(i + 2 * j) % N];
    }
}
```

At this point newMatrix and srcMatrix ought to be identical.

<sup><sup>(Actually, you're already running the *reverse* transformation as your forward one. The one I set up to reverse yours is the one commonly used form for the forward transformation).</sup></sup>

Comment: *Meta:* When you write answers, please look over the question to see whether it can be improved like formatting, tags, title, grammar, etc. It will improve the readability and searchability of the question and might get you more votes. Also, there are tags to be earned.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up; I had actually also forgotten to address a part of the question which might be of more interest than an obscure mapping. Later I'll try and check if there are other SO answers for the negative index topic and add the necessary references.